# Eigenvalues of second order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The question is find all the eigenvalue of the following equation

$-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x^2y=\lambda y$

I have found the first function which is $y=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, however I have no clue on how to find the rest, can someone please help me with it.

Comment: Could you, please, demonstrate why $\exp(-{x^2 \over 2})$ is a solution?

Comment: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ will be equal to $(x^2-1)(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}})$ , put back into the equation we will get $\lambda =1$

Comment: Isn't it in general a lot to ask for explicit solutions to these sorts of eigenvalue problems? The answers Wolfram cooks up are nasty

Comment: How can I get the answer from Wolfram??

Comment: @Joethenerd Putting it into the equation I get $(2x^2-1)y=\lambda y$. This does not look like a solution.

Comment: @lisyarus really sorry for missing a negative sign at the front. The question is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is well-known in quantum physics and goes by the name of [*quantum harmonic oscillator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator). The time-independent Schrödinger equation for this system looks like

$$\left[\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kx^2\right]y=Ey$$

Here, $\hat p = -i \hbar\frac{d}{dx}$ is the momentum operator. The unknowns are the wavefunction $y$ and the energy $E$, - thus, it is an eigenvalue problem.

Setting $\hbar=1$, $m=\frac{1}{2}$, $k=2$ and renaming $E=\lambda$, we get

$$\left[\hat p^2+x^2\right]y=\lambda y$$

Or, expanding $\hat p^2$,

$$\left[-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2\right]y=\lambda y$$

which is exactly your equation.

The solutions to this problem are known; searching for the *quantum harmonic oscillator* you'll find tons of books, articles and lecture notes deriving the solutions.

Comment: Thx for your help, appreciate it!!

Comment: +1 thanks for the complete answer...